# Socket.io doesn't work - site doesn't open in browser

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm starting with Socket.io with Node.js.

I found [this tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1097/simple-chat-nodejs-plus-websockets) and I decided to make my own simple chat based on it. Unfortunately it didn't work. I've done some research but I didn't find anything helpful, so I downloaded source code and run with Visual Studio 2012 and... it still doesn't work :/
Normally when I click "run" button in Visual Studio, appears command prompt and then browser with my site. In this project appears only that:
[image]
and that's it. It seems like something went wrong, I can't access to my server from browser, so it seems like it haven't been created.

This is link to my project: [Download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59608446/ChatUsingWebSocket.zip)

Please, tell my what I've done wrong :/
The worst thig is, that I haven't got any errors, it just doesn't work.

Comment: did you tried to run your application on different port than 80 ?

Comment: u r starting in debug mode.. and thats why it seems like thread is on breakpoint somewhere or on pause.. try running app instead of debug it..

Comment: Your code is working, and the web server is listening on port 3000. Have you tried running it from the command line instead of from Visual Studio?

Comment: yeah, now it works. I don't know why it didn't before...